# You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile (issue not addressed in other posts)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

#### Solution:

Set env variable:

`DISABLE_SPRING=true`

Spring was causing the issue.

#### Problem:

When I run `rake db:migrate` from local machine, I get

> You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.

I can use when is listed here and use

`bundle exec rake db:migrate`, and it works, but, I want to be able to do

`rake db:migrate` without bundle exec.

According to other posts, I should uninstall and reinstall bundler, which I did. I should delete my lock file, which I did. and I should be using 2.6.1, which I am. The commands are being run from the project's root folder.

What other solutions are there? I am using rails 5.2.2 and Ruby 2.6.1

I also get the same error when I run:

```
>> rake credentials:edit
 You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.
```

My setup:

```
>> rvm list
   ruby-2.1.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.4.4 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.5.1 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.5.2 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.5.3 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.6.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default


>> bundler --version
Bundler version 2.0.1
```

Comment: You might try installing RVM, creating a new gemset, running `gem install bundler`, running `bundle install` and then running the rake command from the project root. How are you currently managing your Ruby version? If you're using RVM you shouldn't need to prefix commands with `bundle exec`

Comment: I am using rvm, and when I check the ruby version is shows 2.6.1

Comment: What `which rake` says? (if you're using ohmyzh or similar so that it's overloaded - `sh -c 'which rake'`) It may happen that rake ends up being run by other ruby

Answer (score 0):

I see you've mentioned that you have deleted Gemfile.lock but have you run bundle install after that ? 
This error shows up when the lock file has different bundle than the project file so deleting the lock file and running bundle install must solve the problem.
It always works for me.